# Need to write a regex in C# for numbers only

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex in C# for the following conditions which will be validating a textbox entry :

I should contain either A 5-digit number or a  6-digit number.
In case of multiple entries, the numbers should be separated by a pipe character without space. Example: 34786|235652|12876

I have tried the following regex , which are not working propyl:

```
^\d{5,6}\|?\d{5,6}?$
^[\d{5,6}+][\|?][\d{5,6}?]$
(^\d{5,6}$)|(^\d{5,6}\|?[\d{5,6}*]$)
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d{5,6}(\|\d{5,6})*$
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
^[0-9]{5,6}(\|[0-9]{5,6})*$
```

Explaination:

`^` = Start of line

`[0-9]` = Any digit (`\d` would work too)

`{5,6}` = Either 5 or 6 times

`(...)*` = Whatever is inside the (), 0 or more times

`\|` = The pipe character

`$` = End of line

Put together, it's "Start of line followed by 5 or 6 digits followed by [pipe character followed by 5 or 6 digits] 0 or more times followed by end of line"